# Vectorized way to group a time series by hour of day, on a rolling window, and assign the rolling method to a new column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

We have a time series with a `values` column apart from the `date` column and for every day we have 24 rows (hours of the day). The goal is to create an additional column which contains the **mean of the values for a specific hour of the day on a rolling window**. For example for a rolling window of 365*24 the new column would convey the information: "The `values` column at this hour of the day for the last year had a mean value of X".

The input and output should look something like this for a rolling window of 24:

```
index    date(as datetime64)  values new_column reasoning

0   2021-02-21  00:00:00+00:00  100     -   
1   2021-02-21  01:00:00+00:00  200     -   
2   2021-02-21  02:00:00+00:00  300     -   
3   2021-02-21  03:00:00+00:00  400     -   
4   2021-02-21  04:00:00+00:00  500     -   
5   2021-02-21  05:00:00+00:00  600     -   
6   2021-02-21  06:00:00+00:00  700     -   
7   2021-02-21  07:00:00+00:00  800     -   
8   2021-02-21  08:00:00+00:00  900     -   
9   2021-02-21  09:00:00+00:00  1000    -   
10  2021-02-21  10:00:00+00:00  1100    -   
11  2021-02-21  11:00:00+00:00  1200    -   
12  2021-02-21  12:00:00+00:00  1300    -   
13  2021-02-21  13:00:00+00:00  1400    -   
14  2021-02-21  14:00:00+00:00  1500    -   
15  2021-02-21  15:00:00+00:00  1600    -   
16  2021-02-21  16:00:00+00:00  1700    -   
17  2021-02-21  17:00:00+00:00  1800    -   
18  2021-02-21  18:00:00+00:00  1900    -   
19  2021-02-21  19:00:00+00:00  2000    -   
20  2021-02-21  20:00:00+00:00  2100    -   
21  2021-02-21  21:00:00+00:00  2200    -   
22  2021-02-21  22:00:00+00:00  2300    -   
23  2021-02-21  23:00:00+00:00  2400    -   
24  2021-02-22  00:00:00+00:00  200     150   (i.e the mean of 100 and 200, the values at 00:00 for the 2 days)
25  2021-02-22  01:00:00+00:00  400     300   (i.e. mean of 200 and 400)
26  2021-02-22  02:00:00+00:00  600     450   (i.e. mean of 300 and 600)
27  2021-02-22  03:00:00+00:00  800     etc.    etc.
28  2021-02-22  04:00:00+00:00  1000        
29  2021-02-22  05:00:00+00:00  1200        
30  2021-02-22  06:00:00+00:00  1400        
31  2021-02-22  07:00:00+00:00  1600        
32  2021-02-22  08:00:00+00:00  1800        
33  2021-02-22  09:00:00+00:00  2000        
34  2021-02-22  10:00:00+00:00  2200        
35  2021-02-22  11:00:00+00:00  2400        
36  2021-02-22  12:00:00+00:00  2600        
37  2021-02-22  13:00:00+00:00  2800        
38  2021-02-22  14:00:00+00:00  3000        
39  2021-02-22  15:00:00+00:00  3200        
40  2021-02-22  16:00:00+00:00  3400        
41  2021-02-22  17:00:00+00:00  3600        
42  2021-02-22  18:00:00+00:00  3800        
43  2021-02-22  19:00:00+00:00  4000        
44  2021-02-22  20:00:00+00:00  4200        
45  2021-02-22  21:00:00+00:00  4400        
46  2021-02-22  22:00:00+00:00  4600        
47  2021-02-22  23:00:00+00:00  4800
```

Before even going to making a new column, I thought of trying a `groupby`:

`means = df.groupby(df.date.dt.hour).values.mean()`

However, that has the issue of returning the mean-per-hour for the entire dataframe and not a rolling window of it while a `groupby(df.date.dt.hour).values.rolling(X).mean()` only considers a window of the final grouped results and not a window of the initial data to be considered before grouping, and I don't know how to assign the values to a new column to the initial dataframe since the groupby() results do not have the same index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `droplevel` after `groupby` / `rolling` to drop the level created by `groupby`:

```
# Or .droplevel('date')
df['mean'] = df.groupby(df['date'].dt.hour).rolling(2)['values'].mean().droplevel(0)
print(df)

# Output
                        date  values    mean
0  2021-02-21 00:00:00+00:00     100     NaN
1  2021-02-21 01:00:00+00:00     200     NaN
2  2021-02-21 02:00:00+00:00     300     NaN
3  2021-02-21 03:00:00+00:00     400     NaN
4  2021-02-21 04:00:00+00:00     500     NaN
5  2021-02-21 05:00:00+00:00     600     NaN
6  2021-02-21 06:00:00+00:00     700     NaN
7  2021-02-21 07:00:00+00:00     800     NaN
8  2021-02-21 08:00:00+00:00     900     NaN
9  2021-02-21 09:00:00+00:00    1000     NaN
10 2021-02-21 10:00:00+00:00    1100     NaN
11 2021-02-21 11:00:00+00:00    1200     NaN
12 2021-02-21 12:00:00+00:00    1300     NaN
13 2021-02-21 13:00:00+00:00    1400     NaN
14 2021-02-21 14:00:00+00:00    1500     NaN
15 2021-02-21 15:00:00+00:00    1600     NaN
16 2021-02-21 16:00:00+00:00    1700     NaN
17 2021-02-21 17:00:00+00:00    1800     NaN
18 2021-02-21 18:00:00+00:00    1900     NaN
19 2021-02-21 19:00:00+00:00    2000     NaN
20 2021-02-21 20:00:00+00:00    2100     NaN
21 2021-02-21 21:00:00+00:00    2200     NaN
22 2021-02-21 22:00:00+00:00    2300     NaN
23 2021-02-21 23:00:00+00:00    2400     NaN
24 2021-02-22 00:00:00+00:00     200   150.0
25 2021-02-22 01:00:00+00:00     400   300.0
26 2021-02-22 02:00:00+00:00     600   450.0
27 2021-02-22 03:00:00+00:00     800   600.0
28 2021-02-22 04:00:00+00:00    1000   750.0
29 2021-02-22 05:00:00+00:00    1200   900.0
30 2021-02-22 06:00:00+00:00    1400  1050.0
31 2021-02-22 07:00:00+00:00    1600  1200.0
32 2021-02-22 08:00:00+00:00    1800  1350.0
33 2021-02-22 09:00:00+00:00    2000  1500.0
34 2021-02-22 10:00:00+00:00    2200  1650.0
35 2021-02-22 11:00:00+00:00    2400  1800.0
36 2021-02-22 12:00:00+00:00    2600  1950.0
37 2021-02-22 13:00:00+00:00    2800  2100.0
38 2021-02-22 14:00:00+00:00    3000  2250.0
39 2021-02-22 15:00:00+00:00    3200  2400.0
40 2021-02-22 16:00:00+00:00    3400  2550.0
41 2021-02-22 17:00:00+00:00    3600  2700.0
42 2021-02-22 18:00:00+00:00    3800  2850.0
43 2021-02-22 19:00:00+00:00    4000  3000.0
44 2021-02-22 20:00:00+00:00    4200  3150.0
45 2021-02-22 21:00:00+00:00    4400  3300.0
46 2021-02-22 22:00:00+00:00    4600  3450.0
47 2021-02-22 23:00:00+00:00    4800  3600.0
```